# swipe is not working in bx-slider

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I am working in bx-slider jquery plugin. I tried some options like **touchEnabled**,**swipeThreshold**,**oneToOneTouch**,**preventDefaultSwipeX**.But that is not working.

my code is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" type="text/css" />     
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" title="Funky roots" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_road.jpg" title="The long and winding road" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" title="Happy trees" /></li>
</ul>


$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  mode: 'horizontal',
  captions: true,
  touchEnabled: true,
  swipeThreshold:60,
  oneToOneTouch:true,
  preventDefaultSwipeX:true
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Fcxw/115/

Comment: preventDefaultSwipeX: false if you want to scroll left and right.

Comment: i cant see any difference even if i set preventDefaultSwipeX:true.

Comment: `oneToOneTouch:false, preventDefaultSwipeX:false, controls: false, pager: false` in landscape orientation. `mode: vertical, preventDefaultSwipeY:false` in portrait orientation.

Comment: check this link http://jsfiddle.net/2Fcxw/116/